# Operandtype error: Date is incompatible with int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get a next fiscal date. But I make was wrong. When I want to start a else statement there is a error.

```
declare @kdate date = '2020-07-25'
declare @Period int = 30 -- in days

declare @nextkdate date 
declare @Voption int = 12 -- in months

declare @End date = '2020-08-31'

If @kdate < dateadd(day, -@Period, @End) 
    set @nextkdate = @End
Else set @nextkdate = @End + (dateadd(month, @Voption, @End))


select @nextkdate
```

Where is my fault? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the thinking of having `@End` appear twice in the expression `@End + (dateadd(month, @Voption, @End))`?

Comment: there is a gratis period of 30 days bevor the end date. When this period isnt observe, the next date will be 12 months over. for example: there is a Enddate of contract on 30.09.2020. When the costumer want to end the contract he need to make a desicion till 30.08.2020, otherwise the contract will automatically extend with 12 months, till 30.09.2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `dateadd` alone:

```
if @kdate < dateadd(day, -@Period, @End) 
    set @nextkdate = @End
else 
    set @nextkdate = dateadd(month, @Voption, @End)
```

The call to `dateadd` already adds `@Voption` months to the `@End` date.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `@End + (dateadd(month, @Voption, @End))` is the problem. `@End` is declared as a `date`. [`+ (Addition)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/add-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) says:

> **Arguments**
>
> *expression*
>
> Is any valid [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) of any one of the data types in the
> numeric category except the **bit** data type. Cannot be used with **date**,
> **time**, **datetime2**, or **datetimeoffset** data types.

According to the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [implicit conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-conversions) there is no going back from a `date` to a numeric type, e.g. `int`. Hence the error "Operand data type date is invalid for add operator."